# SQL if subquery from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that has quite many constraints and returns *Items*.
*Items* table looks as follows (simplified):

```
Id | Name | Code
```

And then I have a table *Shelves* that have fields:

```
Item_id | Price
```

From external service I'm receiving codes (`Code` column in `Items)` that should not be in results:

```
(code NOT IN ('" + Joiner.on("', '").join(codesToSkip) + "')
```

And right now I need to change it so if `Item_id` is in table `Shelves` I don't take into account `codesToSkip` received from externla service.

So to summarize:
1. if `Item_id` is in `Shelves` then skip the constraint about `code`

2. if it's not then the `code` constraint must be used.

EDIT:
Query now:

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE Items.code NOT IN ("XX", "WWW")
```

Query after the changes:

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE (Items.code NOT IN ("XX", "WWW") OR Items.id IN Shelves.Item_id)
```

- here is the problem - I want to make it like an if statement - if Item.id from Items is in Shelves then remove the constraint about Items.code

Comment: Make it easy to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: we are using sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `EXISTS` and `OR` in a quite simple where clause:

```
SELECT
  * --TODO, explicit column list
FROM Items i
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Shelves s where s.Item_ID = i.ID)
OR Code NOT IN (1,4,5)
```

Hopefully you can trivially see that if the item is in shelves, it doesn't matter what the `Code` is and only if it is not in shelves that it's then relevant whether `Code` is contained in our list of codes to avoid.

---

Incidentally, you should avoid using double quotes for things intended to be string literals in SQL. The correct delimiter for string literals is the single quote. SQL Server will sometimes allow double quotes instead but I'd not suggest relying on this behaviour.